# Exposing a URL from an application

Tags: apex

I would like to expose a URL from within my Salesforce application, so that someone who goes to a URL like:

salesforce.com/myappscustomurl

Can be redirected to another URL, based on code that runs in an Apex controller. Is such a thing possible? I haven't been able to find anything like this in the documentation?

You might ask why I would want to do this. It is to support a single sign-on scheme with another application. So that users who go to this URL and are authenticated to Salesforce and then use that identity for SSO to another external application. To do this I need to be able to run code before generating the URL to redirect the user to, so I can compute a JWT token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript in your page like below for redirect to another page

```
    <apex:page>
      <script>
        window.location="http://yourURLgoes here";
      </script>
   </apex:page>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I discovered that this page is exposed automatically as /apex/page_name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect using your controller then you have to use **action** function in your Visualforce page that calls your apex Controller method.  You redirection code will be in that apex controller method.

VF Page

```
<apex:page title="abc" action="{!ReDirect}" >

</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public PageReference ReDirect(){
   PageReference p = new PageReference('http://your new URL ');
   p.setRedirect = true;
   return p;
}
```